# switch between 2 angulrjs tabs that using same controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tabs

i am using angularjs-ui tabs in my app.

```
    angular.module('bootstrap.tabset', [])
.directive('tekplntabsets',['tabsetServ', function (tabsetServ) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.templateUrl = '';
            var tabs = $scope.tabs = [];
            var controller = this;

            this.selectTab = function (tab) {
                angular.forEach(tabs, function (tab) {
                    tab.selected = false;
                });
                tab.selected = true;
                tabsetServ.setTabId(tab.tabid);
            };

            this.setTabTemplate = function(templateUrl) {
                $scope.templateUrl = templateUrl;
            };
            this.setTabController = function(tabCtrl) {
                $scope.tabCtrl = tabCtrl;
            };
            this.getTabController = function() {
                return $scope.tabCtrl;
            };

            this.removeTab = function(tab) {
                var index = tabsetServ.removeTab(tab);
                this.selectTab(tabs[index - 1]);
            };

            this.addTab = function (tab) {
                if (tabs.length == 0) {
                    controller.selectTab(tab);
                }
                tabs.push(tab);
                controller.selectTab(tab); 
            };
        },
        template:
          '<div class="row-fluid flexbox flexboxContent divHeight100">' +
            '<div class="row-fluid">' +
              '<div class="nav nav-tabs" ng-transclude></div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="row-fluid flexbox flexboxContent divHeight100">' +
              '<ng-include src="templateUrl" class="flexbox flexboxContent divHeight100" ></ng-include>' +
            '</div>' +
          '</div>'
    };
}])
.directive('tekplntab', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        require: '^tekplntabsets',
        scope: {
            title: '@',
            templateUrl: '@',
            tabid: '@',
            closable: '@',
            tabicon: '@',
            controller:'@'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, tabsetController,  $route) {
            tabsetController.addTab(scope);

            scope.select = function () {
                tabsetController.selectTab(scope);
            };

            scope.$watch('selected', function () {
                if (scope.selected) {
                    tabsetController.setTabTemplate('');
                    tabsetController.setTabTemplate(scope.templateUrl);
                   // scope.$apply();
                    //$route.reload();
                    //if (scope.$parent.tektab.ctrl !== "" && scope.$parent.tektab.ctrl !== "DashboardCtrl") {
                    //    var ctrl = scope.$parent.tektab.ctrl;
                    //    scope.$parent.tektab.ctrl = "";
                    //    scope.$parent.tektab.ctrl = ctrl;
                    //}
                    //if (scope.$root.$$phase !== '$digest' && scope.$$phase !== '$digest') {
                    //        scope.$apply();
                    //    }
                    //scope.$watch('scope.tabid', function (randomValue) {
                    //    scope.$apply();
                    //}); ng-controller="{{controller}}"
                }
            });
            scope.removeTab = function (id) {
              tabsetController.removeTab(id);
            };

        },
        template:
          '<li ng-class="{active: selected}" >' +
            '<a href="" ng-click="select()"><div  class="pointerDiv {{ tabicon }}" ng-show="{{closable}}"></div>&nbsp;{{ title }} ' +
              '<button  ng-click="removeTab(title)" class="TabClose" ng-show="{{closable}}">x</button></a>' +
            '<input type="hidden" value="{{ tabid }}"></input>' +
          '</li>'
    };


});
```

When I am using this directive to open 2 tabs that use different controllers it works well.
**The problem occurs when I want to switch between 2 tabs that using same controller**. (for example, when I open 2 different projects and I want to switch between  project number 1 and project number 2, the tab does not load all the data from project number 2 !!).
I don't want to use angular-ui-router.
**project 1 and project 2 uses same partial html**

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem by using Boradcasting messages